# ASP.NET - Display all Users from AspNetUsers table into Dropdown List in Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

After doing some research, I found ways to do what my question asks, however, I'm trying to do this inside a function called `GetAssignedToDDL` that is of type `List<SelectListItem>`.

After trying some of the answers I found on here and other resources, I keep getting the same error. The error I keep getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'  LWC C:\Users\runningexe\Desktop\LincolnWaterCommissionWorkOrderInventorySystem\LWC\LWC\Controllers\WorkOrderController.cs   201 Active

Is there any way to do this with the function's type being `List<SelectListItem` ? Or is there something else I'm missing here. Like I said, I've tried many solutions that essentially do the same thing, but the error I get is the same.

EDIT: function using Kirk's answer. Now getting an error with my DbContext.

```
private static List<SelectListItem> GetAssignedToDDL()
        {
        List<SelectListItem> assignedToList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var userList = dbContext.Users.ToList();

        assignedToList = userList.Select(u => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = u.UserName,
            Value = u.Id
        }).ToList();

      return assignedToList;
    }
```

What I was trying before:

```
private static List<SelectListItem> GetAssignedToDDL()
            {
              return userManager.Users.ToList();
        }
```

As well as a few other attempts with different code (Same errors). This was the most recent though.

DbContext Error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Comment: How you are writing your code?

Comment: What's the `DbContext` error and what's the type of `assignedToList`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't know why It didn't paste along with everything else. It's of type `List<SelectListItem>` and the error is in my updated post.

Comment: Ok. Looks like my answer covered your initial problem and now you're onto a new one. For this, you'd want to look into dependency injection and how that works in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @KirkLarkin will do. Thanks for taking the time to help :) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) function. On the line where you see the compilation error, try appending the following:

```
.Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.UserName, Value = u.Id }).ToList();
```

If you include your code, I can edit this answer to make it more specific to your use case. You will also need to include `using System.Linq;` if it's not already there.

If you're not familiar with `Select`, it's effectively known as a `mapping` function. You can find a good explanation [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307639/what-does-mapping-mean-in-programming).

Comment: I edited it again to show my most recent attempt. I'm unable to revert back to any others. It isn't much, but it was 3AM and was trying anything at the moment. ha.